# Problems setting up sublime on bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash

I have just bought a new mac (v10.11.4) and have been following the instructions on the link below but can't seem to get my subl shortcut working.

https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170

My .bash_profile now looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I am still getting "command not found" when I try using subl . though. This is my first time setting up a mac for development as I have been given ones that were good to go before, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if there is other basic stuff that I haven't done yet.

Comment: Don't you need to set-up the command line from within sublime text itself?

Comment: Did you `source` your `.bashrc` file like this `source ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: Did you run the `source` command listed on that page or open a new terminal session?

Comment: Sorry for not putting this in the original post, as my rep shows im new at this. So I created the `.bash_profile` file, added in the export PATH as shown above into that file, then ran `source ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal, but it's still saying command not found